# Highcharts xrange timeline overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I am using Highcharts with the xrange plugin, as seen in this [fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s0c2y73d/).

As seen in the dataobject, I have two areas that overlap:

```
data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
            x2: Date.UTC(2020, 11, 2),
            y: 0
        }
        ,{
            x: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
            x2: Date.UTC(2020, 5, 2),
            y: 0
        }
        , {
            x: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2020, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        }]
```

Is there a Highcharts way to group a 'y row' according to the rowLabel, as is done in google charts, as seen below?

```
 var options = {
          **timeline: { groupByRowLabel: true},**
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
          tooltip: { isHtml: false }
      };
```

I would like to create this without creating a new row (e.g. y:3), as this causes spacing, alternating colours and visual confusion in the dataset.

EDIT: Here is what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: How should the final chart look like? Could you post an image?

Comment: @KacperMadej Added as requested

Comment: Unfortunately space for each category is the same. If you need point's to don't overlap you need to use different series: http://fiddle.jshell.net/s0c2y73d/1/